# getting list for documents from external sharepoint site

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

There is a external sharepoint site --> http://(Servername)/FrmsRep/Lists/Sagicor%20Forms%20Repository/AllItems.aspx

I need to get a list for documents from here to my C# webpart.

How would I do that? I've been trying to search but can't find anything :-( OR I do not know what to search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For external sharepoint site you could use

1. [SharePoint Client Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537247.aspx) - it use SharePoint Web Services
2. [SharePoint Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee538665.aspx) e.g. [Lists Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvclists.aspx)
3. [ADO.NET Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee535480.aspx)